# Aggregate Function to dataframe while retaining rows in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, gis

I want to aggregate my data based off a field known as `COLLISION_ID` and a count of each `COLLISION_ID`.

I want to remove repeating COLLISION_IDs since they have the same Coordinates, but retain a count of occurrences in original data-set.

My code is below

```
df2 = df1.groupby(['COLLISION_ID'])[['COLLISION_ID']].count()
```

This returns such:
[image]

I would like my data returned as the `COLLISION_ID` numbers, the count, and the remaining columns of my data which are not shown here(~40 additional columns that will be filtered later)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about filter , we should do `transform`

```
df1['count_col']=df1.groupby(['COLLISION_ID'])['COLLISION_ID'].transform('count')
```

Then you can filter the df1 with column count

Comment: I did this step, but the number of rows are still the same as before. I want each unique COLLISION_ID to be seen as only one record (for example: I have 4 records of one COLLISION_ID). The count field is 4, but there are still 4 columns. I'm looking for only unique COLLISION_IDs

Comment: I can use the .unique() function, but I want that to be translated into a dataframe

Comment: @StevenNac try df=df.drop_duplicates('COLLISION_ID') ?

Comment: That was what was needed, such a simple step, didn't know that function was in Python I am a beginner.  Thank  you very much